# How to resolve url for static asset in S3 with DefaultUrl plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, shrine

i'm having trouble finding the correct way to generate a S3 URL for a public static asset through the [default_url](https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/default_url) plugin in Shrine.
The asset is the users avatar, which can be `nil`, so the idea was to use the plugin  `default_url` to get the empty avatar image. Following the [docs](https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/default_url) I've arrived to this:

```rb
class AvatarUploader < Shrine
  plugin :default_url

  Attacher.default_url do |options|
    '/user_avatar.png'
  end
end
```

But this generates a relative URL. I've also tried using the `:host` option as pointed out [here](https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/default_url#host). But it only works if I hardcode the complete endpoing URL, which is no good.

```rb
plugin :default_url, host: "https://my-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com"

attacher.url #=> "https://my-public-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/user_avatar.png"
```

Other option would be, to set the bucket name in an environment variable:

```
plugin :default_url, host: "https://#{ENV["S3BUCKET_PUBLIC"]}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

but I think is not good either.

Is there a way to programmatically create the full URL directly from Shrine, using its existing configs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To programmatically create the URL I needed to call [Shrine#uploaded_file](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine/blob/0bda9f969a6bd610fdbc93041120dda81b5a7d86/lib/shrine.rb#L129) with an options hash:

```rb
class AvatarUploader < Shrine
  plugin :default_url
  
  Attacher.default_url do |options|
    data = { "id" => "user_avatar.png", "storage" => :bucket_name_from_config }
    shrine_class.uploaded_file(data).url
  end
end
```